# ReactJs setState callback not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a strange behavior with the setState callback, hopefully somebody can help. The callback just isn't fired.

Here is what I do:

```js
this.setState(
  (prevState, props) => {
    return { first: obj, questions: [] }
  },
  this.changeStateCb
);
```

For some reason the changeStateCb function is never being called. Same problem when I change it to:

```js
this.setState(
  (prevState, props) => {
    return { first: obj, questions: [] }
  },
  () => console.log(this.state)
);
```

I just updated from v15.x to 16.2.0

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I've no idea why this is not working. It worked until I updated the reactjs version

Comment: i think same issue has been reported here, try the suggested solution [**Link**](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/1366)

Comment: I do not use react-test-renderer in my application. At least it's not listed in my package.json.Do I have to install the npm package?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a demo? I just put up a simple [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/4xx27l61q7), and it seems to run just fine under React `16.2.0`. Do note though that the optional callback should be used [sparingly](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate). As the docs mention, it will be executed once `setState` is completed and the component is re-rendered. So, a better place to do the logic in `this.changeStateCb` would be inside `componentDidUpdate`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The componentDidUpdate function works. Unfortunately, this is not how it's supposed to work. For me this is just a workaround since I have different setState callbacks in my single component. So I have to create some  logic inside the componentDidUpdate function to call the right callback function which is a bit ugly I would say. Nevertheless I cannot get the setState callback function to be called. I've really no idea why this never happens. It is really strange...

Comment: I've no idea why this is not working in my application. What I can tell you is that it stopped working after upgrading from react v15.x to v16.2. I have some really simple usages of the setState callback. These don't work either

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue happen to me. A simple `console.log('test')` in the callback wouldn't even run. It turns out I had to delete my /dist folder in the build directory. I am using Type Script and webpack and upgraded from a .net core template.

Answer (score 0):

Have the same issue. The callback is not invoked. I traced it to React min code and the function to enqueueSetState does not accept the callback even though it is passed in from internal React code...so code explains why it is not called. But this used to work just fine in React 15.x - what's going on...I am trying React 16.8.4